# This Code wont run due to "Expected Identifier" and "Expected to find ":" " in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
child: Text(
            title,
              style: TextStyle(color : Colors.grey[700], decoration:  _enabledMap[title] == true ?  TextDecoration.lineThrough)
            ),
```

Hi there, I am new to coding and I need help, please can you show me where I'm going wrong

Comment: `_enabledMap[title] == true ?  TextDecoration.lineThrough) : other decoration here`

you miss add else condition for your decoration

Answer (score 1):

You are providing data only for `_enabledMap[title] == true`. But you also need to provide when data is false for ternary case. You can provide null if you don't like to pass any `TextDecoration`

```dart
decoration: _enabledMap[title] == true
    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
    : null
```

For more info, see the [Dart docs on conditional expressions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions)

Comment: Also see the dart docs on ternary operator: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Comment: Feel free to update the answer @L--